# "Learned of" or "Learned about"?

Tags: word-choice, phrases

When would I use "learned of" versus "learned about" in a sentence? For example:

> The principal learned of the planned protest and suspended any students wearing the armbands.

or

> The principal learned about the planned protest and suspended any students wearing the armbands.

Answer (score 6):

The two prepositions seem to indicate different depth or specificity of knowledge.

*Learning of* something is similar to *hearing of* something; it implies a vague or general knowledge.

*Learning about* carries the meaning of having specific knowledge about something. Again, compare to *hear about*.

Comment: This is endorsed by the fact that we say 'learn all about X' but not 'learn all of X' (X an event say; you can 'learn all of the names of the butterflies of the UK', say). Similarly, one only hears 'Hear all abaht it!' I'll leave others to argue over the word class 'all' exemplifies in 'learn all about the planned protest' (one can successfully replace it with 'fully' or 'everything').

Comment: This distinction applies depending on context, though, not always.

Comment: **Kris**, can you give some examples of contexts in which the above would not hold? I don't doubt they exist, just none spring to mind.

Answer (score 4):

Lukewrites' answer is correct; I want to expound on the exact meanings:

- To *learn of* something means to discover its existence (the depth of knowledge is restricted to knowing the thing exists). For example, if I learn *of* the meteor shower tonight, all I know is that there will be a meteor shower tonight.
- To *learn about* something means to discover any amount of knowledge of the thing (the exact depth of knowledge is determined by context). This could be only its existence, or it could be a cursory understanding, or it could be the result of study. So if I learn *about* the meteor shower tonight, I might only know that a meteor shower will happen tonight, or it could be that I have learned that it's the Orionid shower, <sub><sup>and that the Orionids, like all meteors, are composed of debris particles which have been dispersed from Halley's Comet, <sub><sup>and that Earth's path intersects with the comet's debris, <sub><sup>so the Earth's atmosphere experiences a yearly collision with it, in mid-late October. Et cetera.</sup></sub></sup></sub></sup></sub>

In the context of your example, the principal probably didn't need to know about anything more than the existence of the planned protest in order to suspend the students, so *learn of* and *learn about* probably indicate the same depth of knowledge.

So the shade of difference in this scenario is that *learn about* leaves room for an interpretation that the principal learned about a certain ingredient of the planned protest, that caused him to decide to suspend those involved.

Comment: What's up with the rapidly decreasing text size in the 'To learn about' section?

Comment: It's an elaborate et cetera. :) That info isn't germane to the question, but I didn't want my illustration of knowledge depth to be overly scant. Short and long at once.

Comment: But it's not given in Strunk & CMOS! (+1)

Comment: @Daniel I love the rapidly decreasing text idea, very creative :) and now thanks to your answer I could revisit words "germane" and "scant" and their usage in context to help inscribe them into memory :)

Comment: How about the meaning of "learn" not followed by either "about" or "of"?  For example: "He learned the specifications." vs. "He learned about the specifications."  Do they convey different meaning or only one is proper?